Will my contractor need to redo all electric work for new tub?
We have one of those built in jet tubs in our master bathroom which I believe is on its own circuit breaker that has 20a on it.
We have a contractor that will soon be redoing our master bathroom replacing everything including this tub with a free standing tub.
What we currently have is something like this

At the opposite side of our bathroom wall I have something that looks like this:

Every so often when I do use the tub I have to reset it using this button. What I want to do is replace this tub with this:
https://a.co/d/9tax9IB
This tub specifically says this:
“ Pump with durable motor. Innovative technology enables this pump to provide a strong and steady level of hydro-massage; Power Requirement: 110V, 60Hz, 15A dedicated circuit, GFCI outlet to plug into.”
Can I reuse the electrical work from my old tub for this new tub?  If i go downstairs to my breakers I see this:

About fifth one down says “hydro tub” with what appears to say 20a on this switch. I am pretty confident this is specifically for our jacuzzi/hot tub. So does that mean the contractor can reuse most of this setup?
Just looking to see whether this os going to be a large expensive job or not so bad?

The 20 amp breaker may need to be swapped for a 15 amp, but otherwise you should be good to use that wiring and circuit.

@RMDman - but cant we run the new tub 15amp on what is already there 20amp. I would of thought a 20amp could handle something calling out for 15amp. Or maybe it doesnt work that way?

The breaker MAY need to be swapped, was my consideration because the tub instructions may indicate a "Max breaker of 15A"  In that scenario to keep a warranty in place the breaker should be swapped for a 15A.   If the instructions say MINIMUM breaker size 15A, you are fine.

If you have to periodically reset the deadfront GFCI, it may be worth replacing it, or at least inspecting the wiring after demo.  In the 5 years I have been in my current house, the GFCI of the jetted tub my wife likes to use has never needed resetting.

You won't know for sure until after demolition but it sounds hopeful.  The new tub needs a GFCI outlet and it sounds like the GFCI switch in the wall serves the tub.   You'll need to check that, and check everything else that becomes exposed by the demo but it sounds hopeful.   The GFCI looks old, may as well replace it.
The new tub needs a 15A circuit, but a 20A circuit can be used for a 15A device.  You could anyway replace the breaker with a 15A one.
Forgive the gratuitous judginess but a jetted tub on a single 120V 15A circuit is not going to produce much ooh-aah.  It'll make more noise than anything else.  It's a pretty tub, you might consider the plain soaking version if you don't want to invest more in the pump and heater

Thanks this answer makes a lot of sense and seems reasonable. No problem judging the tub. I like the little bubbles it produces which is good enough for me. But i will consider it!  Thanks

Finally installed this and was able to reuse all the existing electrical so barely any additional work was needed. PS believe it or not the bubbling is unbelievable and the entire tub doesnt make a lot of noise at all. Thank you
